# Keep scrolling focused - style CSS flexbox multiple columns with different number of rows

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox, focus

I am building a layout that has a variable number of columns, each having an independent number of rows.

It is not strictly a grid (each column should have equal number of rows), I will call it "board" layout.

Goals :

- user must be able to scroll horizontally only the board, and scroll vertically only the columns: I want to scroll the currently `focused` column and to prevent scrolling in diagonal direction of the whole board.
- Vertical scrolling on column must end when user reaches the end of the column, not of the parent board (the board's height could be longer if there are other columns higher than the focused column).

I wonder if I could achieve this behavior only with CSS - eventually also refactoring the html.

Could you illustrate a possible solution for point 1, 2, using CSS only ?

This is what I tried making use of `flex` css solution.

---

**desired layout**

Columns contains different number of rows and their background is rendered accordingly.

[image]

*attempts*

The following code rendered the desired layout, but if I have many columns, the view port will adjust them *below* the others: instead I want to keep the horizontal order and horizontal scrolling.

```
<div class="board">
    <div class="column>
        <item>..</item>
    </div>
</div>


.board {
}

.column {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  
  width: 20%;
  float:left;
}
```

I tried with this other solution:

```
.grid {
  display:flex;
}
```

and remove `width: 20%; float:left;` in the `column` class.

Now the problems are:

- The user can move the board object in diagonal (see the scrolling-bars on the image): user can only scrolling horizontally the board , and vertically the focused column.
- The shorter columns' height is 'stretched' to meet the max height of the board, resulting in fully colored columns also if there is only element in it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this snippet begins to address all of your desired points. It fixes the board to the size of the viewport and enables horizontal scrolling for horizontal overflow while hiding vertical overflow. Column scrolling is implemented using nested columns set to scroll vertical overflow

(The reason your columns were being pushed into a second row is that you had specified `wrap`.)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.board {  
  background-color: green;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.column{
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  min-width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
.column-inner {
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
div.item {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-inner">
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-inner">
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-inner">
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-inner">
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-inner">
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-inner">
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-inner">
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-inner">
      <div class="item">..</div>
      <div class="item">..</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tks @pilchard! it's neat, I could not test it yet on mobile. I edited a your answer: I fixed a typo, and  included a couple of comments because with current solution a user can still move the board diagonally, which I don't want. I proposed a minor review if you'd like to consider or commented back - plz check it, too.

Comment: Glad it was useful @user305883  I accepted your edit and fixed another typo myself. The minimal diagonal scrolling was being caused by the margin on the `body` element – set the body margin to 0 in my edit and the board is now static.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **scroll-snap**
Here an example with **grid layout**, if you can use it :

```css
.gallery {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 30vw);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 30vw);
    grid-column-gap: 1rem;
    grid-row-gap: 1rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 90vh;
    scroll-snap-type: both mandatory;
    scroll-padding: 1rem;
}

li {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="gallery">
    <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li>Saepe, blanditiis quam!</li>
    <li>Cum, eos reprehenderit.</li>
    <li>Alias, saepe asperiores?</li>
    <li>Fuga, at exercitationem.</li>
    <li>Nihil, magnam! Officia!</li>
    <li>Voluptas, laudantium natus!</li>
    <li>Tempora, quibusdam sed.</li>
    <li>Asperiores, nisi repudiandae.</li>
    <li>Soluta, quas voluptatibus.</li>
    <li>Ipsam, totam saepe.</li>
    <li>Debitis, asperiores ipsum.</li>
    <li>Aliquam, minus corporis.</li>
    <li>Illum, voluptatem maxime.</li>
    <li>Qui, explicabo odio!</li>
    <li>Iusto, nihil illum.</li>
    <li>Iure, numquam facere.</li>
    <li>Possimus, non eos!</li>
    <li>Nesciunt, quas consectetur.</li>
    <li>Accusantium, earum autem!</li>
    <li>Tenetur, asperiores ullam.</li>
    <li>Facilis, adipisci repudiandae.</li>
    <li>Neque, doloribus eligendi!</li>
    <li>Perferendis, vitae suscipit.</li>
    <li>Doloremque, aperiam vitae?</li>
    <li>Assumenda, obcaecati molestias.</li>
    <li>Officiis, laborum omnis!</li>
    <li>Blanditiis, itaque vitae.</li>
    <li>Quis, impedit cumque!</li>
    <li>Omnis, aut repudiandae.</li>
    <li>Laboriosam, quidem ullam!</li>
    <li>Nihil, neque velit?</li>
    <li>Aperiam, voluptatum eligendi.</li>
    <li>Ratione, neque debitis!</li>
    <li>Sunt, ex exercitationem.</li>
    <li>Est, molestias eius.</li>
    <li>Praesentium, nulla molestiae.</li>
    <li>Illum, at nobis!</li>
    <li>Voluptate, tenetur minima!</li>
    <li>Atque, fugit cum?</li>
        <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li>Saepe, blanditiis quam!</li>
    <li>Cum, eos reprehenderit.</li>
    <li>Alias, saepe asperiores?</li>
    <li>Fuga, at exercitationem.</li>
    <li>Nihil, magnam! Officia!</li>
    <li>Voluptas, laudantium natus!</li>
    <li>Tempora, quibusdam sed.</li>
    <li>Asperiores, nisi repudiandae.</li>
    <li>Soluta, quas voluptatibus.</li>
    <li>Ipsam, totam saepe.</li>
    <li>Debitis, asperiores ipsum.</li>
    <li>Aliquam, minus corporis.</li>
    <li>Illum, voluptatem maxime.</li>
    <li>Qui, explicabo odio!</li>
    <li>Iusto, nihil illum.</li>
    <li>Iure, numquam facere.</li>
    <li>Possimus, non eos!</li>
    <li>Nesciunt, quas consectetur.</li>
    <li>Accusantium, earum autem!</li>
    <li>Tenetur, asperiores ullam.</li>
    <li>Facilis, adipisci repudiandae.</li>
    <li>Neque, doloribus eligendi!</li>
    <li>Perferendis, vitae suscipit.</li>
    <li>Doloremque, aperiam vitae?</li>
    <li>Assumenda, obcaecati molestias.</li>
    <li>Officiis, laborum omnis!</li>
    <li>Blanditiis, itaque vitae.</li>
    <li>Quis, impedit cumque!</li>
    <li>Omnis, aut repudiandae.</li>
    <li>Laboriosam, quidem ullam!</li>
    <li>Nihil, neque velit?</li>
    <li>Aperiam, voluptatum eligendi.</li>
    <li>Ratione, neque debitis!</li>
    <li>Sunt, ex exercitationem.</li>
    <li>Est, molestias eius.</li>
    <li>Praesentium, nulla molestiae.</li>
    <li>Illum, at nobis!</li>
    <li>Voluptate, tenetur minima!</li>
    <li>Atque, fugit cum?</li>
        <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li>Saepe, blanditiis quam!</li>
    <li>Cum, eos reprehenderit.</li>
    <li>Alias, saepe asperiores?</li>
    <li>Fuga, at exercitationem.</li>
    <li>Nihil, magnam! Officia!</li>
    <li>Voluptas, laudantium natus!</li>
    <li>Tempora, quibusdam sed.</li>
    <li>Asperiores, nisi repudiandae.</li>
    <li>Soluta, quas voluptatibus.</li>
    <li>Ipsam, totam saepe.</li>
    <li>Debitis, asperiores ipsum.</li>
    <li>Aliquam, minus corporis.</li>
    <li>Illum, voluptatem maxime.</li>
    <li>Qui, explicabo odio!</li>
    <li>Iusto, nihil illum.</li>
    <li>Iure, numquam facere.</li>
    <li>Possimus, non eos!</li>
    <li>Nesciunt, quas consectetur.</li>
    <li>Accusantium, earum autem!</li>
    <li>Tenetur, asperiores ullam.</li>
    <li>Facilis, adipisci repudiandae.</li>
    <li>Neque, doloribus eligendi!</li>
    <li>Perferendis, vitae suscipit.</li>
    <li>Doloremque, aperiam vitae?</li>
    <li>Assumenda, obcaecati molestias.</li>
    <li>Officiis, laborum omnis!</li>
    <li>Blanditiis, itaque vitae.</li>
    <li>Quis, impedit cumque!</li>
    <li>Omnis, aut repudiandae.</li>
    <li>Laboriosam, quidem ullam!</li>
    <li>Nihil, neque velit?</li>
    <li>Aperiam, voluptatum eligendi.</li>
    <li>Ratione, neque debitis!</li>
    <li>Sunt, ex exercitationem.</li>
    <li>Est, molestias eius.</li>
    <li>Praesentium, nulla molestiae.</li>
    <li>Illum, at nobis!</li>
    <li>Voluptate, tenetur minima!</li>
    <li>Atque, fugit cum?</li>
        <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li>Saepe, blanditiis quam!</li>
    <li>Cum, eos reprehenderit.</li>
    <li>Alias, saepe asperiores?</li>
    <li>Fuga, at exercitationem.</li>
    <li>Nihil, magnam! Officia!</li>
    <li>Voluptas, laudantium natus!</li>
    <li>Tempora, quibusdam sed.</li>
    <li>Asperiores, nisi repudiandae.</li>
    <li>Soluta, quas voluptatibus.</li>
    <li>Ipsam, totam saepe.</li>
    <li>Debitis, asperiores ipsum.</li>
    <li>Aliquam, minus corporis.</li>
    <li>Illum, voluptatem maxime.</li>
    <li>Qui, explicabo odio!</li>
    <li>Iusto, nihil illum.</li>
    <li>Iure, numquam facere.</li>
    <li>Possimus, non eos!</li>
    <li>Nesciunt, quas consectetur.</li>
    <li>Accusantium, earum autem!</li>
    <li>Tenetur, asperiores ullam.</li>
    <li>Facilis, adipisci repudiandae.</li>
    <li>Neque, doloribus eligendi!</li>
    <li>Perferendis, vitae suscipit.</li>
    <li>Doloremque, aperiam vitae?</li>
    <li>Assumenda, obcaecati molestias.</li>
    <li>Officiis, laborum omnis!</li>
    <li>Blanditiis, itaque vitae.</li>
    <li>Quis, impedit cumque!</li>
    <li>Omnis, aut repudiandae.</li>
    <li>Laboriosam, quidem ullam!</li>
    <li>Nihil, neque velit?</li>
    <li>Aperiam, voluptatum eligendi.</li>
    <li>Ratione, neque debitis!</li>
    <li>Sunt, ex exercitationem.</li>
    <li>Est, molestias eius.</li>
    <li>Praesentium, nulla molestiae.</li>
    <li>Illum, at nobis!</li>
    <li>Voluptate, tenetur minima!</li>
    <li>Atque, fugit cum?</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: tks @bluebird, this grid representation does not satisfy the scrolling requirements: I can scroll diagonally. I have multiple columns with different numbers of items. I want to scroll horizontally the columns, and vertically the items. But prevent diagonal scroll on the wrapper.